# Python plays an "error" sound instead of playing .wav

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been having an issue where instead of my code playing back a sound file it makes a "dun-nun" sound, I've tried several modules such as pygame, winsound and playsound (below) but all of the have the same issue. For context my script is at the same directory level as the file and I'm running windows 10.

```
    from playsound import playsound
    sound="some file.wav"
    playsound(sound)
```

Comment: What sound plays when you double-click on "some file.wav"?

Comment: *"my script is at the same directory level as the file"* Okay, but what's the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) set to?

Comment: When opened in a media player "some file.wav" plays correctly.

Comment: The working directory is set to ".".